Vector analysis text book.
I saw in the post orthogonal to the level curve
a few screenshots from a textbook, and I would like to know if by any chance someone knows that text book's name, I tried searching the images in Google but it just redirects me to the post.

Judging by the user's previous calculus question three days earlier, this looks to be some version of Calculus: Early Transcendental Functions by Robert T. Smith and Roland T. Minton. I can't make it line up with the preview, but the graphics and design seem to match.

It is "Calculus: Early Transcendental Functions" by Robert T Smith and Roland Minton.
I found it here on page 876. It seems to be a matter of luck whether Google shows this page on a preview or not, but I have seen it, and if you search for "occurring in the direction opposite the gradient", you get this page as your only result.
